# Azure blob storage as ROR's Dragonfly data store

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, datastore, dragonfly-gem

With EngineYard recently [adding Azure's IAAS](https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/giving-our-customers-more-choice-with-windows-azure) in their bucket, one of our client is deciding to migrate to Azure blob storage.

In the application, we are using predefined S3 [data store settings](http://markevans.github.io/dragonfly/file.DataStorage.html) for dragonfly and in there, other settings are available for various cloud services as well.

Has anyone implemented dragonfly's data store for Azure blob storage?